# Windows 8.1 stops responding to ping after user has signed off

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop, windows-8.1

When i sign out of my win 8.1, it stops responding to pings from my other machine.

This win 8.1 is installed on a laptop, so I guess this may be a power plan issue, but currently I have power plan that allows everything even on battery, also, i disabled turning off my ethernet card in device properties.

The issue is very annoying, because it practically disallows me to connect to the laptop through RDP (since rdp first needs to sign out current user, and that disables the network on laptop). It is double weird, because when I sign out, windows shows this "network monitor" icon at the botton, which looks like everything is working ok. But it isn't - when I run `ping myLaptop -n 100` it works until I sign out of the machine, then pings stop responding.

What can I do here? Are there maybe any power options beside mentioned by me above that may relate to my problem?

Comment: Is it connected on wifi?

Comment: It disconnects from the network, (on logon screen wifi is up, but not connected). I can connect it from this logon screen, which I do, and then it appears on the network. But as soon as I close the lid, it disappears again. It looks like there is some stupid power plan that does this, because what else could cause this behavior?

Comment: Windows does have a setting on the adapter to allow os to switch of wifi to save power, uncheck that box if Windows 8 has the option. Also since wifi device is in the screen part of laptop generally, I have heard that wifi signal may not reach it when you close the lid as it was designed to have laptop open. Maybe give it a static ip too